# Objective-C How to compress images and videos to decrease data usage for app?

Tags: objective-c, video, compression, avfoundation

So I am currently developing an app that essentially allows users to send and retrieve videos and images. When I was using the app while on LTE wifi, it used nearly 160 MB in an hour while apps like FB and instagram use significantly less data (Fb only used 2.1 GB and it's been a year).

So my question is, how can I reduce the amount of data plan my app uses. I'm assuming the reason it uses so much is cuz I'm sending 1MB videos and retrieving 1MB videos a lot. How should I deal with this? Should I compress the videos? What size should a video be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebP image format for your photos. Its a format used by Google in their applications, and is [well documented](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/using). First [convert your images to this format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/precompiled), then load them in your app using [this](https://github.com/seanooi/iOS-WebP). I use this in my application and it has cut my data in half.

Comment: But I wanna store the images in Amazon s3, can I store webp images in s3?

Comment: Also I'm mainly worried about videos rather than images. Any advice on videos?

Comment: Like how does youtube, instagram, facebook and such store videos efficiently? What should a video be compressed to in average (10 second video)

Comment: @Adp I know youtube uses the DASH protocol and has several servers set up across the world that have pieces of each video locally available [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqQk7kLuaK4). I'm not sure how facebook/Instagram does it but I imagine that it is similar. Being such large companies, I imagine they have more resources available than an Amazon s3 Server.

Comment: @Adp For now, I would try to look at the different [video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs) and compression formats, and try to find the one that has the best quality for the lowest file size

Answer (score 0):

For video compression you can use [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession) custom class. You can download it from this [link](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession).

After downloading add SDAVAssetExportSession.h and SDAVAssetExportSession.m files into your project, Then the below code will help to do the compression. **In below code you can compress video by specifying resolution and bitrate**

```
#import "SDAVAssetExportSession.h"


- (void)compressVideoWithInputVideoUrl:(NSURL *) inputVideoUrl
{
    /* Create Output File Url */

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *finalVideoURLString = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"compressedVideo.mp4"];
    NSURL *outputVideoUrl = ([[NSURL URLWithString:finalVideoURLString] isFileURL] == 1)?([NSURL URLWithString:finalVideoURLString]):([NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalVideoURLString]); // Url Should be a file Url, so here we check and convert it into a file Url


    SDAVAssetExportSession *compressionEncoder = [SDAVAssetExportSession.alloc initWithAsset:[AVAsset assetWithURL:inputVideoUrl]]; // provide inputVideo Url Here
    compressionEncoder.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    compressionEncoder.outputURL = outputVideoUrl; //Provide output video Url here
    compressionEncoder.videoSettings = @
    {
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: @800,   //Set your resolution width here
    AVVideoHeightKey: @600,  //set your resolution height here
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: @
        {
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @45000, // Give your bitrate here for lower size give low values
        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264High40,
        },
    };
    compressionEncoder.audioSettings = @
    {
    AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @2,
    AVSampleRateKey: @44100,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: @128000,
    };

    [compressionEncoder exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         if (compressionEncoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {
            NSLog(@"Compression Export Completed Successfully");
         }
         else if (compressionEncoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Compression Export Canceled");
         }
         else
         {
              NSLog(@"Compression Failed");

         }
     }];

}
```

To Cancel Compression Use Below Line Of code

```
 [compressionEncoder cancelExport]; //Video compression cancel
```